# Deconvolution in Tensorflow vs. Caffe

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, caffe, deconvolution

What are the differences between the Deconvolution layer in Caffe and Tensorflow? In Tensoroflow, there are two padding modes: "SAME" and "VALID", which one is equal to padding mode that was used in Caffe?

For example, in Tensorflow, the Deconvolution layer is:

```
decv = slim.convolution2d_transpose(in_layer, num_outputs=256, kernel_size=[8, 8], stride=4, padding='VALID', scope='decv')
```

And in Caffe, it is:

```
layer { 
  name: "decv"
  type: "Deconvolution"
  bottom: "some_layer"
  top: "some_layer"
  param { lr_mult: 1 decay_mult: 1.0 }
  param { lr_mult: 2 decay_mult: 0}
  convolution_param {
    num_output: 256
    pad: 1 stride: 4 kernel_size: 8
    group: 256 
    weight_filler { type: "bilinear" }
  }
}
```

I can not achieve the same upsampling map when transfer the code from Caffe to Tensorflow.

Answer (score 0):

'VALID' means no padding, but your Caffe layer is padded with pad: 1.

Try 'SAME' padding